# Core Graphics won't load all the way for certain buttons

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, gradient, uibezierpath, cgrectmake

I am coding a button background of a simple red gradient, which works when the height is less than 100, but will simply stop loading the gradient if the button is larger than that and I can't figure out why. I am using PaintCode (which up until now has worked like a charm) to draw the code, then I changed the size of the gradient from `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 120) cornerRadius: 4];` to `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) cornerRadius: 4];` because the size of the button changes between 4.5" and 5" devices. I am using other gradients with identical codes minus the color on other buttons and they work perfectly fine. It is only when the height is greater than 100 pts that I find a problem. Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
//// General Declarations
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Color Declarations
UIColor* lightRedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0.188 blue: 0.098 alpha: 1];
UIColor* darkRedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.812 green: 0.016 blue: 0.016 alpha: 1];

//// Gradient Declarations
NSArray* redGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id)lightRedColor.CGColor,
                              (id)[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.102 blue: 0.057 alpha: 1].CGColor,
                              (id)darkRedColor.CGColor, nil];
CGFloat redGradientLocations[] = {0, 0.5, 1};
CGGradientRef redGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)redGradientColors, redGradientLocations);

//// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) cornerRadius: 4];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[roundedRectanglePath addClip];
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, redGradient, CGPointMake(120, 0), CGPointMake(120, 120), 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);


//// Cleanup
CGGradientRelease(redGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Edit: here is a screenshot of the button:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a screen shot? Are there other views which could be covering the button?

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot - thank you for that. Also, there are no other views that could be covering it.

Comment: Add a border to the button and to its superview so you can 100% see where they are (you can recursively do it to all views if you want).

Comment: I created a border, and it extended all the way to the bottom of the button and nothing is in the way of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, redGradient, CGPointMake(120, 0), CGPointMake(120, 120), 0);`

Here you are specifying the height of the gradient area to draw, with an end point of y=120. This means your gradient will be 120 points high regardless of the code above it. Change the end point to be `CGPointMake(120, self.bounds.size.height)` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is `[roundedRectanglePath addClip];`. Specifically, that a clipping path has been specified on the current graphics context somewhere else in the code and either not been removed when it should be (missing call to `CGContextRestoreGState`) or it is set to a smaller size than it should be.

Check for clipping paths that have been added and not removed. Also check for superviews set to clip subviews and whose size is not correct.